# How to integrate graphviz in angular

Tags: angular, d3.js, graphviz

Iam using Angular7 and d3.js already.
Now I would like use d3-graphviz(https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-graphviz) or viz.js(https://github.com/mdaines/viz.js) or something else what works to display the DOT-graphs.

None of the approaches works. And I cant find any hints in the web. 
Now I need some assitance how to get it running inside my App.

e.g:
-what npm package?
-which configs? (angular.json,  tag or just "import as..")
-and/or a small working example like:

```
        d3g
        .graphviz(d3.select(this.svg.nativeElement))
        .renderDot('digraph {a -> b}');
```

Iam thankfull for any hint. 
It would help if someone already managed it to get it run.

I already tried any approach showed in the documentations and the combination of using native JS libs in Angular.

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import * as d3g from 'd3-graphviz';

...
d3g
    .graphviz(d3.select(this.svg.nativeElement))
    .renderDot('digraph {a -> b}');

OR

d3
    .select(this.svg.nativeElement)
    .graphviz()
    .renderDot('digraph {a -> b}');
```

Just need to see an Graphviz diagram in my angular web app.

Comment: any error messages?

Comment: I have lot of errors, diffrent on each approach.
Bottom line is the problem that I cant instantiate "Viz" inside angular. What I can make is: `Viz = require("viz.js/viz.js");` and than `new this.Viz()` but than it needs WebWorker arguments and so on.

Answer (score 3):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { graphviz }  from 'd3-graphviz';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'd3-graphviz in Angular';

  ngOnInit() {
    graphviz('div').renderDot('digraph {a -> b}');
  }
}
```

See https://github.com/magjac/d3-graphviz-angular for a full example.

Comment: works for me: https://stackblitz.com/github/magjac/d3-graphviz-angular?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I cloned this git, but I had some trouble running _npm install_, so I changed this devDependency and it cleared the issue:
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.8",